# At what point did Einstein realise that gravity was curvature of spacetime?

Tags: physics, astronomy, einstein

Did he realise this as soon as he thought of light curving due to gravity or was this something that took him a while to realise?

Comment: Your question is of the form "When did Einstein realise X?," but X isn't true. A more correct statement would be that mass causes spacetime to curve. Einstein gives some motivation for the idea in "The Foundation of the General Theory of Relativity," Annalen der Physik 49 (1916) 769. There is a public-domain translation in the back of my GR book: http://lightandmatter.com/genrel/

Comment: The "gravity causes other mass' gravity to curve" phrasing is perplexing to me, what does that mean? That the light would curve due to gravity, and even black holes, were discussed already in Newtonian physics, see http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3421/what-was-the-longest-delay-between-prediction-and-confirmation-of-a-theory/3429#3429 Einstein's path to general relativity is described here http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3547/why-did-einstein-develop-general-relativity/3550#3550

Comment: I'll just edit the title to eliminate the misstatements.

Comment: I think that the OP is perhaps asking about the nonlinearity of the Einstein field equations, and when Einstein realized that a nonlinear theory would be required (?).

Comment: I'm sorry but I have the same question. *Minkowski's geometric interpretation of relativity was to prove vital to Einstein's development of his 1915 general theory of relativity, wherein he showed how mass and energy curve flat spacetime into a pseudo-Riemannian manifold.* - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime *Einstein combined (postulated) the equivalence principle with special relativity to predict that clocks run at different rates in a gravitational potential, and light rays bend in a gravitational field, even before he developed the concept of curved spacetime.*  - **Cont'd**

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle .  In other words, when Einstein realized that the curvature of Minkowski's flat spacetime is the same as gravity. I believe that Einstein had already realized that gravity affect time, gravity cannot travel faster than the speed of light, and also that gravity can bend light which was known since Newton's time. Was it that when Einstein combined all these factors into a mathematical formulation, it became apparent to him that it would result into the curvature of Minkowski's flat spacetime. Possibly, this curvature of flat **Cont'd**

Comment: spacetime makes the general theory of relativity non-linear.  Please let me know if I should this question again in a new post. Thanks.